# What is the SiteMinder application server?

Tags: windows-xp, jboss

What is the SiteMinder application server? There seems to be very little documentation on what this is.

The follow-up question would be, do I need to set up JBoss / WebLogic / WebSphere.

I am using a 32 bit Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

Web findings:

> The SiteMinder Application Server
>   Agent protects resources on Java 
>   application servers that follow the
>   Java 2 Enterprise Edition standard.
>   These  resources can be Java servlets,
>   JavaServer Pages (JSPs), and
>   Enterprise  JavaBeans (EJBs).
>
> When a user requests a resource from
>   an application server, the Agent 
>   intercepts the request and determines
>   whether the resource is protected by 
>   SiteMinder. The SiteMinder Application
>   Server Agent consists of two
>   components: **Java servlet Agent** — a
>   collection of servlets that
>   communicates with the Policy Server
>   via the SiteMinder Agent API. **EJB
>   Agent** — a component that integrates
>   with the application server  and
>   communicates with the Policy Server
>   like the servlet Agent. The  EJB Agent
>   protects only EJBs. In the absence of
>   an Application Server Agent, you can
>   use a Web Agent to  protect
>   application server resources; however,
>   the Application Server Agent  can
>   protect resources at a more
>   fine-grained level than a Web Agent.

The original document is [here](http://rtfm.cc.emory.edu/doc/siteminder/siteminder-agent-guide.pdf).
And you can find other SiteMinder documents [here](http://rtfm.cc.emory.edu/doc/siteminder/).